# WHERE clause overwriting field value

Tags: mysql

The following query accurately returns the value `w.price` however `w.time` is given as `2017-11-23 15:12:00` which is not the correct value from the row returned. However, it consistently matches the `WHERE time >=` clause. What is causing this to happen?

```
SELECT
    history.pair_id,
    MIN(history.price) as all_time_low,
    history.time as all_time_low_time,
    w.price as one_week_price,
    w.time as one_week_time
    FROM ep_ex_waex history

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(price) as price, time, pair_id
    FROM ep_ex_waex
    WHERE pair_id = 2
    AND time >= '2017-11-23 15:12:00'
) as w ON w.pair_id = history.pair_id
```

**Result**

```
+---------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| pair_id | all_time_low | all_time_low_time   | one_week_price | one_week_time       |
+---------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
| 2       | 392.3        | 2017-11-23 12:11:00 | 396.77         | 2017-11-23 15:12:00 |
+---------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------------------+
```

Not the column `all_time_low_time` is correct.

**ep_ex_waex structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `ep_ex_waex` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pair_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double NOT NULL,
  `volume` double NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You are having issue with aggregation of time.  Could you show us the result you are getting?  It would also help if you could give us an example of the `ep_ex_waex` table.

Comment: thanks @tukan I've updated the OP

Comment: MySQL will let you be vague about which row it selects for a value when you aggregate, but you should be explicit as to what you want wherever possible. Also, you may need/want to group by one of your columns.

Comment: Thank you, how can I be explicit? I've set table aliases and attempted that route, but no luck.

Comment: The rule of thumb is to put in the group by section all columns that you are not using an aggregation.

Comment: Your query will definitely blew up in every other databases, except for maybe MySQL because it doesn't make sense.  When you do aggregation, all the non-aggregated columns must be in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Thanks both but I'm still not following; group by isn't solving this problem either. `time` should not equal the `WHERE` clause, it should equal the time field from the row selected, which is in fact `2017-11-30 14:09:00`

Comment: If you're still struggling, see See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: On further investigation, it is not returning the value of the `where` clause but the first row's `time` field value. Does that make things clearer? Even without using `INNER JOIN` and just adopting a simple query it still errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this mod will focus the result, using a WHERE to locate the price based on the pair_id and MIN.

```
SELECT price, time, pair_id
   FROM  ep_ex_waex ep 
   WHERE pair_id = 2
   AND time >= '2017-11-23 15:12:00'
   AND price = (SELECT min(price) FROM ep_ex_waex WHERE pair_id=ep.pair_id);
```

Your full query would look like this:

```
SELECT
  history.pair_id,
  MIN(history.price) as all_time_low,
  history.time as all_time_low_time,
  w.price as one_week_price,
  w.time as one_week_time
  FROM ep_ex_waex history

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT price, time, pair_id
  FROM ep_ex_waex ep
  WHERE pair_id = 2
  AND time >= '2017-11-23 15:12:00'
  AND price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM ep_ex_waex eps WHERE eps.pair_id=ep.pair_id)
) as w ON w.pair_id = history.pair_id;
```

It could probably be optimized a lot to not use so many subqueris, but hopefully you get the idea.

Good luck.

=== TEST CASE ===
Data used:

```
+-------+---------------------+---------+
| price | time                | pair_id |
+-------+---------------------+---------+
|  1.29 | 2017-11-23 15:12:00 |       2 |
|  1.19 | 2017-11-24 15:12:00 |       2 |
|  1.79 | 2017-11-25 15:12:00 |       2 |
+-------+---------------------+---------+
```

Query:

```
mysql-sql>     SELECT price, time, pair_id
        FROM ep_ex_waex ep
        WHERE pair_id = 2
        AND time >= '2017-11-23 15:12:00'
        AND price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM ep_ex_waex eps WHERE eps.pair_id=ep.pair_id);

+-------+---------------------+---------+
| price | time                | pair_id |
+-------+---------------------+---------+
|  1.19 | 2017-11-24 15:12:00 |       2 |
+-------+---------------------+---------+
```

That looks right to me, found the middle record, lowest price, and matching date.  Break your query down into segments and see if you can get it working.

Comment: Sadly not; even the *simplest* query: `SELECT MAX(price), time FROM ep_ex_waex WHERE pair_id = 19 AND time >= '2017-11-23 12:11:00'` returns the wrong time. How is that even possible...

Comment: I created a simple test case and it worked for me, see my edited answer.